# Does S3 sync use/support multipart uploads?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to backup a bunch of large binary artifacts to AWS S3. The artifacts do change but not often. Hence I am looking to sync rather than upload. But since these files are a few GBs in size, I am looking for multipart upload. What does ***sync*** use under the hood? Can I direct it to use multipart uploads?

Comment: By `sync`, I assume, you mean `aws s3 sync`? It's open source.  Have you looked inside?

Comment: yes. I did mean `aws s3 sync`. could not understand from the code but was able to verify using the ETag generated for a particular file. `s3 sync` and `s3api put-object` generated the same Etag for the object whereas `s3api upload-part` generated a different one

Answer (score 0):

Have written a custom tool for S3 syncing for ***a single file*** with the capability of multi-part uploads. https://github.com/mikhailadvani/aws_s3sync. It is also available through pip

Comment: When you post a link to your own site, [it's important to clearly disclose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/1695906) the fact that you are linking to your own site.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear when he said "have written a custom tool", that this is his own tool that he's making available.